# prefill not working in razorpay

Tags: php, payment-gateway, razorpay

```
$data = [
        "key"               => $api_key,
        "amount"            => $amount,
        "name"              => "DJ Tiesto",
        "description"       => "Tron Legacy",
        "image"             => "logo.png",
        "prefill"           => [
                                    "name"     => "Daft Punk",
                                    "email"    => "customer@merchant.com",
                                    "contact"  => "9999999999",
                               ],
        "notes"             => [
                                    "address"           => "Hello World",
                                    "merchant_order_id" => "12312321",
                               ],
        "theme"             => [
                                    "color"    => "#F37254"
                               ],
        "order_id"          => $razorpayOrderId,
    ];
```

I am trying to integrate razorpay with php everything is ok but in prefill, I get a default value. how can I change this value to custom value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prefill you will get the value which you are given in the prefill object. Just like you passsed $amount and $razorpayOrderId you can use $name and $email etc which might be the value you get from textbox or something like that. Store those names and email in a variable and pass that into prefill.

Answer (score 2):

you can easily change the default value by fetching those values from database or pass those values through  ulr parameters as i have done in php.

get order id through url parameter or post request

$orderid = $_GET['orderid'];

> run php mysql query to fetch data from database based on order id(i
>   have used 2 table one for payment details and another one for
>   userdetails)

```
$query = "SELECT ud.Name, ud.lname,
ud.MobileId,ud.EmailID,opd.pay_amount, opd.receipt, opd.transaction_id
FROM online_payment_details as opd
INNER JOIN userdetails as ud 
ON opd.user_id=ud.UserID
WHERE order_id='$orderid';";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row['Name'].' '.$row['lname'];


$razorpayOrderId    = $orderid;
$amount_pay         = $row['pay_amount'];
$receipt            = $row['receipt'];
$transaction_id     = $row['transaction_id'];
$displayAmount      = $amount_pay ;
$corporateName      = '';
$email              = $row['EmailID'];
$contact            = $row['MobileId'];
```

> now in your data array add above variables in data array

```
$data = [
        "key"               => $keyId,
        "amount"            => $amount_pay,
        "name"              => $name,
        "description"       => "",
        "image"             => "",
        "prefill"           => [
        "name"              => $corporateName,
        "email"             => $email,
        "contact"           => $contact,
        ],
        "notes"             => [
        "address"           => "Hello World",
        "merchant_order_id" => $transaction_id,
        ],
        "theme"             => [
        "color"             => "#F37254"
        ],
        "order_id"          => $razorpayOrderId,
        "receipt"           => $receipt,
    ];
```

> and now in checkout/automatic page in  block fetch values from
>   data array and store in data attribute as below

```
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="<?php echo $data['key']?>"
    data-amount="<?php echo $data['amount']?>"
    data-currency="INR"
    data-name="<?php echo $data['name']?>"
    data-image="<?php echo $data['image']?>"
    data-description="<?php echo $data['description']?>"
    data-prefill.name="<?php echo $data['prefill']['name']?>"
    data-prefill.email="<?php echo $data['prefill']['email']?>"
    data-prefill.contact="<?php echo $data['prefill']['contact']?>"
    data-notes.shopping_order_id="<?php echo $data['receipt']?>" 
    data-order_id="<?php echo $data['order_id']?>"

    <?php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data-display_amount="<?php echo $data['display_amount']?>" <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data-display_currency="<?php echo $data['display_currency']?>" <?php } ?>
  >
  </script>
```